# On the right-angled fork track of alpha particles

Tags: experimental-physics, radiation, scattering, history

In high school we were told that the idea "alpha particles are actually helium nuclei" came from observing the right-angled fork track, produced by placing an alpha source in a diffusion cloud chamber filled with helium.

From the point of view of the Geiger-Marsden Scattering Experiment, an alpha particle hitting a helium nucleus is an extremely rare event. Besides, there is no guarantee at all that the alpha particles would not hit the nuclei of other gas molecules in the chamber.

**So my question is:** How did people discover this extremely rare event (sit there and stare at the chamber for hours?), and why were they so sure that it was a helium nucleus that the alpha particle hit?

Comment: What's wrong with sitting there and staring at the chamber for weeks? :-) Not sure it takes that long, but setting up these experiments often takes years and nowadays decades, so you better have a lot of patience and a tolerance for delayed gratification in science. Apart from that, of course, you don't need to wait for an almost 90 degree event, you can analyze the distribution of angles, my best guess is that they probably just can't teach that in high school because of the necessary time constraint/missing calculus.

Comment: *"why were they so sure that it was a helium nucleus that the alpha particle hit?"* That part is surprisingly easy. An alpha particle and a Helium-4 nucleus have the same mass (because they are the same thing, natch). It's a nice result from non-relativistic conservation of momentum that two equal mass things will elastically scatter at right angles to one-another in the lab frame (where one was initially at rest).

Comment: @dmckee A right angle scattering shows that an alpha particle hit something with the mass of an alpha particle. Why were they so sure it was a He nucleus? I would guess that putting the cloud chamber in a magnetic field and watch the radius of the path would be part of it. If you knew how fast the particles were traveling, you could show the charge was +2.

Comment: So, while admitting that I don't know the historical background (hadn't heard of this particular experiment before) we can make a number of guesses.  (A) They could easily measure the mass-to-charge ratio of an alpha particle and could compute that a helium nucleus (or a $\mathrm{He}^{2+}$ ion if done before the nuclear model was around) also has that ratio. (B) They get those tracks when they added helium to the gas in the cloud chamber.

Comment: I also would like to say that—like a number of other experiments from that era—there is an elegance to this work that comes from the necessity of working around extremely limited tooling.